# how to manage dart packages in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a package A and B
in package **A**, i add **shared_preferences: 0.5.12** to pubspec.yaml
in package **B**, i add **shared_preferences: 0.5.10** to pubspec.yaml
is this correct or i should use the same package version in different packages? if YES, how can i guarantee the dependencies of the other libraries from pub.dev using the same version.

When i create myApp, i will add package A and B in myApp, should I also add shared_preferences to myApp?(yes).
Can someone explain how to share pacages or use packages across different packages?

Comment: why do you want to use different packages ?

Answer (score 0):

Your package version should look like:

```
some_package: ^1.2.1
```

where `1.2.1` is what you tested.  This lets pub pick any version 1.2.1 or greater, up to just before 2.0.0, which should be the first breaking interface change.

See https://semver.org for the meaning of the numbers, and https://dart.dev/tools/pub/versioning#semantic-versions for the specifics about the pubspec.yaml.